# keyerror:0 (df can work but df[0] cannot)

Tags: python, pandas

When I tried to call `df[0]` it showed `KeyError: 0`, but I can call `df` and it worked just fine. Can't understand why `df` worked but `df[0]` did not.

```
    import pandas as pd
    url="https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data"
    df = pd.read_csv(url,dtype=str) 
    print df
    print df[0]
```

Comment: What do you think `df[0]` should do?

Comment: @pault I thought it would return the data in the first row

Comment: Read this: pandas [Indexing and Selecting Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html).

Comment: To get the first row, use `df.head(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df[0]` would give you a `Series` for a column `0`, which you don't have (but e.g `df[' State-gov']` would work).

To get the first entry, use `df.iloc(0)`

[Documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)